# Remove width & height in CKEDITOR

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using Ck-editor in drupal sites. If i add the image from ck-editor through URL, it automatically assign the height and width value. I need the width and height field but the value should not be assign after paste the URL on URL field..
How can i achieve this.

Comment: Looking for something similar, did you ever find an answer?